# To remove unused files from assets folder on my pc in my project of Android Studio.(using Android,Html, javascript)

Tags: android, image, android-studio, hybrid-mobile-app, space

Need to remove unused files from assets folder on my pc in my project of Android Studio.
The structure is as follows: assets - images

Tried 1.refactor- remove unused resources, 2.analyze - inspect code- remove unused resources,3.QA plugin. But no luck.
Since there are huge no of images can't perform the activity manually.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: At runtime the assets resource is read only for your app

Comment: Thankyou for your time.So you mean to say that assets folder is run time available? How can I remove the unused files from assets?

Comment: Well ... if it is read only then... what do you think? Not at runtime!

Comment: Okay.Any insights/reference how to achieve ?

Comment: Why do you want to remove them at runtime?

Comment: I don't remove at runtime.I wanted to remove the unused files /images from the codebase .Instead of doing it manually but do it using tool /IDE options/plugins

Comment: Then why didnt you say so at the start of your post? The first line still suggest that you wanna do it at runtime.

Comment: May I know where exactly I mentioned as runtime?

Comment: `from assets folder in the hybrid application` is something different from  `from assets folder on my pc in my project of Android Studio.`

Comment: Thank you for highlighting . Now can you please provide your insights

Comment: The easiest is to use the directory explorer on your pc. If you right click on the assets folder visible in Android Studio there is a menu option Show in Exporer.

Comment: Actually, it's a hybrid application and it has huge collection of files.Out of which I need to remove unused images.

Comment: Well ok. Please do.